# Removing title bar in an activity removes images also

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code in my layout class `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` to remove the title bar. It is working fine as it is removed the title bar. But unfortunately, it also removes the images I put inside the activity.

I am using constraint layout and I already infer constraint. I also tried putting inside my manifest on application level the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` code, but whenever I run the app, it says application has stopped.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To hide title bar for specific activity do this
set these lines in onCreate on the activity class

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and in activity layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

and remove AppBarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your activity - onCreate method -

`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Then add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

**in your manifest file look like**-

```
<activity
            android:name=".EmailValidation"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" />
```

I hope this will be help you.

Comment: it says `cannot resolve symbol in android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

Comment: where you put this- `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` -in  your project?

Comment: inside application level

Comment: I update the answer please tell me-  are you work abobe like this?

Comment: add those line in style - `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`

Comment: I already did what you instructed, but same thing, it successfully removed the title bar, but it also removed the images I put inside my activity.xml